# temperature loss in a metal surface

Tags: temperature, thermocouple

A metal cone is heated at certain temperature  . say 45 -50 deg C. i placed a thermocouple(k type) over the surface of the metal  to measure the heat transferred over the metal surface.  The thermocouple reads about 45 to 50 deg C (which is expected) .
But the issue is when i put a plastic cap over the metal cone ,the temperature drastically decreases . So i think am missing some thermal fundamentals here which i couldnt recognize .

EDIT : The heating setup is used to heat the plastic cap which is put over the metal cone.Without the plastic cap the metal surface heats up fast.When the plastic  cap is placed it struggles to increase and reach atleast 44 deg C.

Comment: you mean when you put a plastic between the surface you want to measure and your thermocouple?

Comment: no the plastic cover is put on the metl cone where the thermocouple is placed .So the plastic covers both metal cone and thermocouple

Comment: I suspect the cap puts some stress on the thermocouple and makes the thermal coupling between TC and cone worse. How do you ensure that the TC sticks to the cone when the cap is put into place?

Comment: I glued the thermocouple on the metal cone surface.it fits fine & and the position remains unchanged even after removing the cap .

Comment: A picture or two would help, but when adding a plastic cap to what I assume is your heater, you will also have to heat the plastic cap up.

Comment: actually the heater setup is used to heat the plastic cap .But when pplastic cap is inserted the measured temperature suddenly drops and it struggles to reach atleast 44 deg C .

Comment: Picture? What kind of metal and what surface treatment? What kind of plastic, what kind of surface?

Comment: sorry i dnt have a pic. The metal cone is made of mild steel and there is no coating upon it. The plastic is  thin form of pvc i guess.

Comment: The point of my question is emissivity and surface smoothness. If you have surface A, which is smooth metal you can increase it's emissivity for many, many alloys by coating it with a coarser surface or one of higher emissivity.

Comment: since its is not coated ,the surface is slightly coarse. But i wonder why the temperature takes much time to increase when plastic cap is mounted .

Comment: _Because_ the plastic cap can drastically change the emissivity as well. If you have a pail of water with a small hole in it, you need to add x water per minute to keep it full. If you then make the hole twice the diameter, you need to add 4*x to keep it full. Thermodynamics of surface emissivity is somewhat similar. If the metal surface has an emissivity much lower than the plastic surface, your slamming a larger hole in your model.

Comment: In any case, this is an [engineering.SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) question, not an electronics question.

Answer (score 1):

The plastic cap (you say it is thin) has some heat capacity, but it also has surface area and a shape. It may be acting to increase the heat loss to ambient.

The details of heat loss by natural convection are **not** simple- depending on whether you have laminar or turbulent (or transitional) flow (see 'Reynold's number'..) you can have quite different heat transfer rates.